# How do I iterate, dynamically load my form input elements and then retrieve the input values on Form Submit in React?

Tags: reactjs, json, forms, react-props

I am creating a sample dynamic form and I want to load my input elements based on a JSON which contains different input elements like "textbox", "text-area", "dropdown", "radio-input" and so on..
**I have a JSON file created to get this as shown below:**

```
[ 
    {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "textbox",
        "text": "",
        "required": true,
        "label": "lbl"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "textbox",
        "text": "",
        "required": true,
        "label": "Specification Name"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "type": "dropdown",
        "text": "",
        "required": true,
        "label": "Specification Reviewed",
        "options":["a","2"]
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "type": "dropdown",
        "text": "",
        "required": true,
        "label": "Action Required",
        "options":["1","2","3"]
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "type": "textbox",
        "text": "",
        "required": true,
        "label": "lbl"
    }
]
```

I have an App base component which calls another component called "Input" which has my layout and I retrieve the elements through that component. I am able to pull the text box and dropdown here but I am not able to iterate through the dropdown select. I'm not sure how to do it.

**Here's my App Base solution:** Here I use the map concept to fetch the data from the JSON local file and assign it to *inputvalues* which I then use in the *return* within the form tag.

1. I'm able to list all my input elements dynamically
2. *But I'm not able to get the dropdown values from my JSON file*

```
    function App() {
      const [inputObject, setInputObject] = React.useState(inputData)
      const inputvalues = inputObject.map( input => {
        return (
            <Input 
                    key={input.id}
                    input={input}
                    />
        )
    })
    
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <form>
            <div>
              {inputvalues}
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} />
          </form>
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }

export default App;
```

**And, here's my input.js component file:** This basically lays out the input elements and I fetch the data using Props but I am unable to fetch the dropdown selection values because I would need to somehow iterate within each of those dropdown elements.

```
export default function Input(props) {
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    textBoxValue: ""
  })

  function handleChange(evt) {
    setState({ [props.input.id] : evt.target.value });
  }
   if (props.onChange) {
     props.onChange(state);
      }
return (
    <div>
        <label>{props.input.type}: </label>
        {props.input.type === "textbox" && <input name={props.input.type} placeholder={props.input.type} id={props.input.id} value={state.firstName} onChange={handleChange}/>}
        {props.input.type === "dropdown" && <select name={props.input.type} id={props.input.id}>
            <option value={props.input.options}></option></select>
}</div>)}
```

Please help me or guide me because I'm still learning React.
In addition to this, how would i later get all the input values upon FORM SUBMIT ? For this I tried adding a *handleChange* event to see if data comes through but it does not work.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [Yup and Formik](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial#schema-validation-with-yup) useful.
With Yup, you can include types to fields as well as things such as if the field is required.
The example linked should get you in the right direction.

#### Edit - (after OP comment)

So without using any external library, you could do something like this:

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const INPUTS = [ 
  {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "textbox",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "label": "lbl"
  },
  {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "textbox",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "label": "Specification Name"
  },
  {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "dropdown",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "label": "Specification Reviewed",
      "options":["a","2"]
  },
  {
      "id": "4",
      "type": "dropdown",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "label": "Action Required",
      "options":["1","2","3"]
  },
  {
      "id": "5",
      "type": "textbox",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "label": "lbl"
  }
];

const convertArrayToObject = (array, key, targetKey) => {
  const initialValue = {};
  return array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    return {
      ...obj,
      [item[key]]: item[targetKey],
    };
  }, initialValue);
};

const Form = () => {
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(
    convertArrayToObject(INPUTS, "id", "value")
  );
  const handleChanges = (keyName) => (e) => {
    const newValue = e.target.value
    setFormState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [keyName]: newValue
    }));
  }
  
  console.log(formState);
  
  return (
    <form>
      {INPUTS.map((input, inputIndex) => (
        <div key={inputIndex}>
          <label htmlFor={input.id}>{input.label}</label>
          {input.type === "dropdown" && input.options ? (
              <select onChange={handleChanges(input.id)}>
                {input.options.map((option, optionIndex) => (
                  <option
                    key={optionIndex}
                    value={option}>{option}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            ) : (
            <input
              id={input.id}
              name={input.id}
              required={input.required}
              type={input.type}
              onChange={handleChanges(input.id)}
              value={formState.value}
              />
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
    </form>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render(
  <Form />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

#### A little reasoning behind some of the code written:

- React wants a `key` prop to be passed when mapping over objects (hence I've added it for each wrapper `div` and `option` element.
- I've mapped over the `INPUTS` object to build the initial state, and then created an `onChange` handler that is curried, that way it is generic enough to be used everywhere
- I'm just `console.log`ing the `formState` to demonstrate the changes as you update the form.

#### Beyond

- Consider adding [Auto Complete](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Autocomplete_Types) if applicable or worthwhile

You will of course need some kind of some kind of submit button if you plan to submit the data to an API.

```html
<button type="submit">Submit</button
```

But I will leave that as an exercise for you...

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was thinking of not using another library for this - can I not do an iteration within each of my dropdown element like the iteration i do at the input element level ?

Comment: @Kay ok no problem, check out the Snippet in the now edited post

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped - i was able to iterate through the child options for dropdown and was able to get the dropdown values to show up in the front end! I now need to get the form submit to fetch all the values that have been input which I will work on based on your solution.